# Raspberry Pi input reading through endless while loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm detecting a touch throuth a ttp223b touch sensor via python on a raspberry pi. It works pretty good but i need to wait for a second after a touch detection to prevent more than one execution so i just added a "time.sleep(1)".

The problem is that i also get multiple outputs, they are just time offset to 1 second, it seems that the routine is triggering multiple times at once.

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN)


while 1:

  if GPIO.input(3) == GPIO.HIGH:
    print "touched :3"
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any suggestions how i could solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

add a sentinal

```
last_update = 0
while 1:
   if time.time() - last_update > 1.5 : #1 and a half seconds
          if GPIO.input(3) == GPIO.HIGH:
              print "touched :3"
```

this will allow the GPIO to continue flushing so you dont pick up the old press (at least I think im not entirely sure how GPIO buffers work here)

Comment: I've also tried a similar way but your solutions is unfortunately not working, same multiple output as before :(

Comment: are you sure the pin is not actually high?

Comment: I've solved it, the problem was caused by an i2c programm. PIN 3 was not in use but i guess the internal pull-up resistor kept the pin HIGH for a longer time. I've just used another GPIO pin and it works perfect, thank you very much!